# Show that $\pi(n) \geq \log_2\log_2 2n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Doing some excercise on elementary number theory I have proved that for every $n \in \Bbb{N}, p_{n+1} \leq p_1p_2...p_n + 1$, based on this result I'm also was able to prove that for every $n \in \Bbb{N}, p_{n} < 2^{2^n}$. Based on this I have now to show that for every $n \in \Bbb{N}, \pi(n) \geq \log_2\log_2 2n$, where $\pi$ is prime counting function. Here is what I tried.

In order to $r=\log_2\log_2 2n$ be in $\Bbb{N}$, let $n=2^m, m \in N$. Then I got $r=log_2\log_2 2(2^m)=\log_2\log_2 2^{m+1}=\log_2 m+1$. Once again, let $m=2^r - 1$, then $r=\log_2 {(2^r-1) + 1}=\log_2 2^r=r$. Substituting $m$ to $n$ I have $n=2^{2^r-1}$, and initial inequality becomes $\pi(2^{2^r-1}) \leq r=\log_2\log_2{2^{2^r}}$.

From this point, If I consider prime $p_r$, it's true that $\pi(2^{2^r}) \geq r$, because it's already proven that $p_{r} < 2^{2^r}$, so there is an $r_{th}$ prime between $1$ and $2^{2^r}$. But I can't figure out why it's also true for $\pi(2^{2^r-1})$. And that's where I stuck and need some help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think $p_n < 2^{2^n}$ is sufficient to show that $\pi(n) \ge \log_2(\log_2(2n))$. Consider $n = p_m$: The inequality to prove is $m \ge \log_2(\log_2(2p_m))$. Using $p_m < 2^{2^m}$ would yield $m > \log_2(2^m+1)$, which isn't true.

Comment: Is the "Based on this" for showing $\pi(n) \geqslant \log_2 \log_2 (2n)$ explicitly the inequality $p_n < 2^{2^n}$, or is it the result $p_{n+1} \leqslant p_1p_2 \cdot\ldots\cdot p_n + 1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, well, the excercise itself consists of three sequential subtasks: A) prove that $p_{n+1} \leq p_1p_2...p_n + 1$; B) using A, prove that $p_n < 2^{2^n}$; C) using B show that $\pi(n) \geq \log_2\log_2 2n$

Comment: That's unfortunate, since from B) alone you cannot reach C). It is compatible with B) that for some $k > 1$ you have $p_k = 2^{2^k} - 3$. Then take $n = 2^{2^k} - 3$, thus $\pi(n) = k$. But $2n > 2^{2^k}$, hence $\log_2 \log_2 (2n) > k = \pi(n)$. But from A) you can reach C) by proving a slightly stronger version of B). Are you interested in that?

Comment: Note that $\pi(n)\ge\log_2\log_2(2n)\iff2^{\pi(n)}>\log_2n$ for $n\ne2^k,k\in\Bbb N$ so we want to show that $\pi(n)>\log_2\log_2n$ for such $n$. However, $p_n>2^{2^n}$ by itself only implies $\pi(n)>\left\lfloor\log_2\log_2n\right\rfloor$ which is weaker than what we want to prove.

Comment: We can even obey the letter of the law by using B) to prove a slightly stronger version of B) from A) that suffices ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer, I think it's ok to use A :)

Comment: @VarunVejalla, not quite sure why $p_m < 2^{2^m}$ yields $m > \log_2(2^m+1)$. Like if use $p_m = 2^{2^m-1}-1$, then there's still $m > \log_2\log_2(2^{2^m}-2)$, just like for $p_m = 2^{2^m-1}+1$ there is $m \geq \lfloor\log_2\log_2(2^{2^m}+2)\rfloor$

Comment: I think I've been mistaken, using B) I seem to not get a strong enough version. But from A) alone I get one.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, the thing I don't get is why there is $2^{\pi(n)} > \log_2 n$ and not $2^{\pi(n)} > \log_2 2n$

Comment: @DanielFischer, could please you provide your A-based version an answer?

Comment: I'm afraid it is uglier than I thought, the $2n$ instead of $n$ in the $\log_2 \log_2$ argument destroys all beauty :( Oh, well, so be it.

Comment: Because $\pi(n)\ge\log_2\log_2(2n)\iff2^{\pi(n)}\ge\log_2(2n)=1+\log_2n\iff2^{\pi(n)}>\log_2n$ for $n\ne2^k,k\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we choose $n = p_{k+1} - 1$, we see that for $\pi(n) \geqslant \log_2 \log_2 (2n)$ to hold for all $n$ we must have
$$p_{k+1} \leqslant 1 + 2^{2^k-1}$$
for all $k$. Unfortunately I don't see a nice induction for that using
$$p_{n+1} \leqslant p_1p_2\cdot \ldots \cdot p_n + 1\,, \tag{1}$$
thus I'll do something more ugly and prove
$$p_k < 2^{2^{k-1} - 1} \tag{2}$$
for $k \geqslant 3$ using $(1)$ and $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3$.

The base case is immediate,
$$p_3 \leqslant 2\cdot 3 + 1 = 7 < 8 = 2^3 = 2^{2^2 - 1}\,.$$
Then in the induction step for $n \geqslant 3$ we have
$$p_{n+1} \leqslant 1 + \prod_{k = 1}^{n} p_k < 1 + 2\cdot 3 \cdot \prod_{k = 3}^{n} 2^{2^{k-1} - 1} < 2^3\cdot 2^{2^{n} - 4 - (n-2)} < 2^{2^n-1}\,.$$

And then, for $n \leqslant 8$ we verify $\pi(n) \geqslant \log_2 \log_2 (2n)$ by inspection, for $n > 8$ we choose $k$ such that
$$2^{2^{k-1} - 1} < n \leqslant 2^{2^k - 1}\,.$$
Then $k \geqslant 3$, and by $(2)$ we have
$$\pi(n) \geqslant k = \log_2 \log_2 \bigl(2^{2^k}\bigr) \geqslant \log_2 \log_2 (2n)\,.$$

Not pretty, and that for a ridiculously weak lower bound :(

Answer (score 1):

You can be able to obtain a stricter bound for $\pi (x)$ since the Prime Number Theorem states that:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi (x)}{x/\log(x)}=1$$
But to obtain a lower bound different from this huge theorem is not so hard. You can use Bertrand's postulate to get a lower bound. There is an elementary proof for this postulate, you can get the "$\textbf{idea}$" of the proof on Wikipedia. Now by Bertrand's postualate:
$$\pi (n) -\pi \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right) \geq 1$$
$$\pi \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)-\pi \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor\right) \geq 1$$
$$...$$
$$\pi (2) - \pi (1) \geq 1$$
Now since there are $\left\lfloor \log_2 n\right\rfloor$ terms, add them together, we obtain:
$$\pi (n) \geq \log_2 n$$
The rest which is to prove $\log_2 n \geq \log_2 \log_2 2n$ is obvious since $n \geq \log_2 2n$ can be proved by induction and take logarithm to the desired inequality.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Here is one thing I concern about. Given $2^n \geq \log_2 2n$ and taking it's logarithm it becomes $n \geq \log_2\log_2 2n$, which is not yields $\log_2 n \geq \log_2\log_2 2n$ as $n \geq \log_2 n$

Comment: Sorry, my typos.